# Read date stamp from .csv into matlab - need faster code

Tags: performance, matlab, date, csv, time

i have data in a csv file that looks like this. A timestamp and data, approximately 200 000 rows per file.

```
2015-10-19T22:15:30.12202 +02:00,62.7
2015-10-19T22:15:30.12696 +02:00,58.5
etc
```

I want to import it into matlab and convert the timestamp to a numeric format. The data is stored in a matrix of size N x 2. It should look like this:

```
736154.4935, 62.7
736154.4955, 58.5
etc
```

Looking only at the date conversion, below is the code i use. rawdata{2} is the vector of time strings ("2015-10-19T22:15:30.12696 +02:00"). I have to do an extra calculation since datenum only supports milliseconds, and not further.

```
for i = 1:length(rawdata{2})
    currDate = strsplit(rawdata{2}{i}, ' ');
    currDate = currDate{1};
    add_days = str2double(currDate(24:25))/(100000*3600*24);
    timestamp = datenum(currDate, 'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.FFF')+add_days;
    data(i,1) = timestamp;
end
```

I have 1000+ files that each have 200 000+ rows like this. My code works, but it's too slow to be practical. Is there any way i can speed this up?

EDIT: After using profiling as suggested in the comments I found that `strsplit` took the most time. Since `strsplit` isn't really necessary in this case I was able to cut significant time off!

Now `datenum` is what takes up the majority of the time, but I'm not sure i can get around it. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: What is "too slow to be practical" in this context? This is a lot of data just to read in, much less process. I suggest [profiling your code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) with a subset of your data to see where the time is being spent. Also, what version of MATLAB?

Comment: It's somewhere around 5 minutes per file, and i will read thousands of files in total (however i only need to read it once). Matlab version R2015b. I will look into profiling. Thankyou for your help!

Comment: @Goatcat: Profiling your code not only tells you how fast it is, it also tells you which line takes how long!

Comment: I suggest investigating the [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) class, introduced in R2014b, which has higher precision than `datenum`.

Comment: Consider [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/e4a1d3946f69cb54b992) for an example.

Comment: I tried your example but i don't understand how i'm supposed to use datetime to make a numerical date.

Comment: [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) accepts `datetime` inputs, but *why* do you need numerical dates?